# How to make this variable reference `final`, how do I get this to compile cleanly?

Tags: java, final, idioms

I want to make the `result` variable `final`, how do I structure this code so that this compiles cleanly? I know I have done this in the past, but I can't remember how I structured it to make it work.

The following code is a `straw man` example, the code I am trying to clean up is much more complicated, this is just distilling the essence of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
private boolean someMethod()
{
    final boolean result;
    try
    {
        // do the logic here that might throw the following
        // exceptions
    }
    catch (final IOException ioe)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    catch (final ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I can't put the `result = true` in the `try` block because it won't compile with both the catch blocks complaining that the final variable might already be assigned.

I can't put it in a `finally` block because that would generate the same complaints as in the `try` block?

**I want to be able to set `result =` once and only once.**

**So where do you set `result = true;` to get it to compile cleanly?**

Comment: Why make a local variable `final`?

Comment: I make everything `final` as much as possible because it makes debugging much easier, **documents the intent that the variable should be assigned once and only once**, and is a optimization hint to the compiler in most cases as well. I am not hear to argue this aspect, I **know** making as many variable references as possible `final` increases the quality of a code base tremendously.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: To me, in this case, this "optimization" decreases the code quality (i.e. readability). There's no reason to declare `result` as `final`, especially when it will make your method needlessly more complicated. Other than this case, I agree wholeheartedly with you. :)

Comment: this is a straw man for the question, this isn't actually the code I am trying to get to work as I desire, it doesn't make it more complicated it makes it more readable, and the compiler will catch errors if the other places in my code that need to set this try to over write it.

Comment: _the compiler will catch errors if the other places in my code that need to set this try to over write it_? IT'S A LOCAL VARIABLE!

Comment: @sthupahamaht you don't get it, in cases like this it doesn't matter if it is `local` or not, I don't want the variable to be written to but `once` and `only once`.

Comment: @Jarrod: Oh, alright. That makes more sense. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot simpler to not set a variable.

```
private boolean someMethod() {
    try {
        // do the logic here that might throw the following
        return true;

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // handle IOE
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        // handle CNFE
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. Why set a final variable that you are just going to return? the original example didn't sit with me well from a design standpoint.

Comment: **this is a solution to the goal I was trying to achieve**, `return` in a bunch of `catch` clauses is not good, and a immutable `result` isn't good either. As I read this answer, I remember now this is the approach I have taken in the past, thanks for jogging my memory.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to use `final` to enforce "assign exactly once" is always tricky. You can use a second variable:

```
private boolean someMethod()
{
    boolean res;
    try
    {
        // do the logic here that might throw the following
        // exceptions
    }
    catch (final IOException ioe)
    {
        res = false;
    }
    catch (final ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
    {
        res = false;
    }
    final boolean result = res;
    return result;
}
```

But the real question is, why not just remove the `final` qualifier?

Comment: Either this, or remove the `try-catch` block and make `someMethod` throw `IOException` and `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: it is documentation that this should only be set once and only once, it makes it really hard to make errors and aids in debugging.

Comment: this answer doesn't achieve my goal. I don't want to pollute the rest of my code with exceptions that are unrelated to its operation

Comment: @Jarrod - I don't think the flow analysis that the compiler carries out will let you do this kind of assignment in catch blocks. One could argue that it ought to be able to do so, but it just doesn't. I'd suggest not fighting city hall on this and just replace the `final` declaration with a simple comment above the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reassign a value to a `final` variable, so this is impossible.

edit: It's also a contradiction to want to declare a variable that is local to a method as `final` and also change the value in the same method - why is it necessary to declare it as `final` at all in this method?

Comment: I haven't set it to anything, I am not trying to re-assign it, I am trying to assign it **only once**, either to `true` or `false`.

Comment: But `final` means you can only assign once in the same statement as the declaration - thus it cannot be declared and then assigned in a block like this. Why not just remove the `final` modifier from the declaration, seeing as how this is a local variable only?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a local variable as `final` within a method then the value of that variable cannot be changed within the method.

Remove the `final` from the declaration of `result`, or get rid of the `result` local variable altogether and return directly from within the `catch` blocks and the end of the method.

Comment: returning from inside a bunch of `catch` blocks is terrible practice.

Comment: returning from multiple places in a method is bad practice to begin with, it is the flip side of `GOTO`, thus returning from multiple catch blocks is bad practice.

Comment: An interesting read, thank you. That wasn't the most important point of my answer though, which was to get rid of the `final` or remove the `result` local altogether, just as Peter suggested in his accepted answer.